# How to get an customized image as label for office add in menu? C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, add-in, ribbon

As the title say. I have an office add in for word and want the label (menu name) for my ribbon to be an customized image from my desktop. How do I add my image as label? Check the picture below to see an example..

[image: Image to show where I want to add my customized image]

I am using C# and visual studio (for the first time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fluent UI doesn't allow placing images instead of text for tab captions.

You can read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I suspected this were the case but was hoping for some solution.